# Server-less applications - how to

Tags: serverless-framework

I would like to get started with server-less applications but not sure which languages can be used?  I am constantly searching Google for any tutorials or any information but I am coming up short.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Also, how do server-less apps differ from other web apps?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a big buzz word for : `not managing your own servers` and infrastructures. No big deal whatsoever. For node(maily) there is https://serverless.com/

At the end of the day, it's the same thing for your web app and server-side. Just managed differently.

Pretty much like "the cloud", we treat it like if it was mythical beast.